# How to model simple interacting systems with Green functions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, many-body, greens-functions

I'm reading Fetter Walecka on many body theory (Chapter 7). We have established the from of the many body green function
\begin{equation}
    G(xt,x't')=\langle T \psi(xt)\, \psi^{\dagger}(x't')\rangle
\end{equation}
in the Lehmann representation
\begin{equation}
    G(k,\omega)=\int_0^{\infty}dE \, \frac{A(k,E)}{\omega -\mu-E+i0}+\frac{B(k,E)}{\omega -\mu+E-i0}
\end{equation}

$A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite spectral functions. In the section on the physical interpretation, F&W make "*an elementary model of the interacting assembly and assume that $G^R(\omega,k)$ has a simple pole close the the real axis at $\omega = \epsilon_k - i \gamma_k$ with residue $a$*" (note that $\gamma$ is finite).

A short calculation yields

\begin{equation}
    G(k,t) = -i a e^{-i \epsilon_k t}\, e^{-\gamma_k t},
\end{equation}
which describes the propagation of a quasiparticle with energy $\epsilon_k$ and lifetime $1/\gamma_k$.

Question: What is the microscopical justification for the simple pole at $\omega = \epsilon_k - i \gamma_k$? It seems to contradict the Lehmann representation, because the latter shows that all poles are infinitesimally close to the real axis.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10921/how-to-get-an-imaginary-self-energy This post might help answer your question.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/429301/where-are-the-poles-of-the-one-particle-greens-function-located-in-the-complex?noredirect=1&lq=1 This one also may help! Essentially this says that even though the integrand of the spectral representation that you have written has poles at $\mu + E - i0$ and $\mu + E + i0$, the integral(i.e $G(k,\omega)$) can have poles at energies that have a finite imaginary part.

Comment: Interesting. This helps indeed.